# Nest js. Using firstValueFrom for send in ClientKafka not async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, apache-kafka, rxjs, nestjs

I am using @nestjs/microservices for work with kafka in microservices. And ClientKafka one of them. The method "send" returning Observable, but I wanna Promise, so I used rxjs/firstValueFrom to get Promise from Observable. But when I await it, I don't get async.

```
import { HttpException, Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ClientKafka } from "@nestjs/microservices";
import { firstValueFrom } from "rxjs";
import { AssetGetOneDto } from "./dto/asset.get.one.dto";
import { AssetTransferDto } from "./dto/asset.transfer.dto";

@Injectable()
export class AssetService {
   constructor(
       @Inject("ASSET_SERVICE")
       protected readonly assetClient: ClientKafka
   ){}

   async onModuleInit() {
       this.assetClient.subscribeToResponseOf('asset.get.one')
       await this.assetClient.connect()
   }

   async onModuleDestroy() {
       await this.assetClient.close();
   }

   async oneAsset(assetGetOneDto: AssetGetOneDto) {
       const response = await firstValueFrom(this.assetClient.send('asset.get.one', assetGetOneDto))
       console.log("response=",response)
       if(response.status == 200){
           return response.message;
       }
       return undefined;
   }
}
```

Client creating:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from "@nestjs/microservices";
import { getuid } from "process";
import { ConfigModule } from "src/config/config.moudle";
import { ConfigService } from "src/config/config.service";
import { AssetService } from "./asset.service";

@Module({
    imports: [
        ClientsModule.registerAsync([
            {
                name: "ASSET_SERVICE",
                imports: [ConfigModule],
                inject: [ConfigService],
                useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
                    options: {
                        client: {
                            clientId: 'asset',
                            brokers: [configService.getBroker()]
                        },
                        consumer: {
                            groupId: 'asset-consumer-'+process.pid,
                        },
                    }
                }),
            }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [AssetService],
    exports: [AssetService]
})
export class AssetModule {}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not `async`? What is, or isn't happening?

Comment: When app waiting for response from kafka, he doesn't answer to any requests

Comment: What if you use `lastValueFrom`? Same thing? What does the microservice controller look like?

Comment: Are you sure `send` in kafka gives you a "Response" back? I think the promise will resolve when the message has been sent, but kafka doesn't work as a "request-response" pattern

Comment: @JayMcDoniel , also tried, but it's same. I also tried deprecated method toPromise()

Comment: @olivarra1 , the send method returns an observable that I can subscribe to. But yes, you are right, and there is a problem with kafka. But is there a solution for await  reply (response) event? Sorry for the foolish question

Comment: Personally, I'd just keep with using Observables. Easier than switching context between rxjs and promises, but that's my opinion